# PhoneAuthProvider.credential confusing return type

Tags: flutter

How come these 2 are not the same

`PhoneAuthProvider.credential` on vscode

```
AuthCredential credential(
{required String verificationId,
 required String smsCode}
)
```

`PhoneAuthProvider.credential` on [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/PhoneAuthProvider/credential.html)

```
PhoneAuthCredential credential(
{required String verificationId,
required String smsCode}
)
```

This is how I use PhoneAuthProvider.credential

```
final PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
          PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: editProfileController.verificationId,
              smsCode: smsCode);
```

which gives this error

```
A value of type 'AuthCredential' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'PhoneAuthCredential'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it fixed!, just cast `AuthCredential` into `PhoneAuthCredential`

```
final PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential =
          PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId: editProfileController.verificationId,
              smsCode: smsCode) as PhoneAuthCredential;
```

Answer (score 0):

PhoneAuthCredential means just phone number authentication but auth credential means different types of authentication like emailAuthCreadential, oAuthcredential as well phoneAuthCredential. That's why those two are not the same.
For better understanding, you should follow the [link](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/AuthCredential-class.html)

Comment: Yes I understand that PhoneAuthCredential inherit from AuthCredential. However, that is not the problem. The problem is that the definition of this function `PhoneAuthProvider.credential` is not the same between the vscode extensions and the docs. On vscode this function returns `PhoneAuthCredential` where on the docs say it returns `AuthCredential`